# PyQt5 button background color not taking effect

Tags: python, pyqt5

Here is the button's code:

```
    self.pushButton.setFont(font)
    self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.0568182, y1:0.126, x2:0.75, y2:0.227, stop:0.0738636 rgba(0, 255, 0, 255), stop:0.840909 rgba(0, 136, 0, 255));\n")
    self.pushButton.setFlat(True)
    self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
```

Although I set a background gradient to this button, it's not taking effect.

Here's the button normally:

[image]

Here's when it's pressed down:

[image]

Comment: Docs from http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html:
Warning: If you only set a background-color on a QPushButton, the background may not appear unless you set the border property to some value. This is because, by default, the QPushButton draws a native border which completely overlaps the background-color.

Comment: Sorry but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. It's solved.

The problem was, I was using **background-color** but **background:#fff** did the trick.

Comment: I'm curious why this worked.  As far as I could see there is no documentation that says to do this.  Why did you try this, and where is the documentation for it?

Comment: I've no clue either. There is no documentation that says so

Comment: I did some research on this.  It's easy to find a dozen or so links where someone else is having this exact same problem.  There appears to be some weird interaction between Qt palettes, stylesheets and the OS.  If there is someone out there who actually understands it, he's not talking.  Your solution is very interesting and I did not see anyone else who has done it this way.